# Open source contribution is hidden on careers profile

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

I've contributed to the [MongoDB C# driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/commit/0b94545542b8ae5782727335a697c8fb585689eb) and it's hidden on my careers profile since "We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project"

I've realized that I probably made a mistake and used my work email instead of my personal email when authoring the commit, however GitHub does connect that commit to my account and I've since added the work email to my github account which didn't help.

Is there something to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a regular job that runs to check for commits. When this ran a couple of hours ago, it picked up your commit so that project is now visible publicly on your profile.

Comment: Just wondering, how often does this run? Daily?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure It runs continually through all GitHub repos on Careers, least-recently-updated first. It can be a few weeks between updates for any particular repo.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just one more question (I promise this is my last!): When you say updates, do you mean in terms of repositories being added or "updated" here, or in terms of most recent commit or something else on Github itself? (The former seems to make the most sense but I just wanted to double check.) Thanks for your time!